# jQuery get content of textarea

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to get the content of my textarea when onkeyup event triggered.
I tried this:

```
<textarea onkeyup="getContent(this)"></textarea>


function getContent(txtBeschreibung) {
   console.log(
    txtBeschreibung.val()
   )
}
```

but my output is this:

```
TypeError: txtBeschreibung.val is not a function. (In 'txtBeschreibung.val()', 'txtBeschreibung.val' is undefined)
```

Where is my mistake? :/

Comment: `txtBeschreibung` is not a jQuery object, it's an `HTMLTextareaElement` DOM object, from which you can get the value by getting the `value` property like `txtBeschreibung.value`. No jQuery involved.

Comment: `console.log(
    txtBeschreibung.value
   )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txtBeschreibung` isn't a jQuery object, to use jQuery, you could do this

```
function getContent(txtBeschreibung) {
   console.log($(txtBeschreibung).val());
}
```

or in Vanilla JS:

```
function getContent(txtBeschreibung) {
   console.log(txtBeschreibung.value);
}
```

Comment: ahh okay ! I see. Thank you ! :)

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using a jQuery selector for an element you get as paremter.

Comment: @Ghost108 - no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get your code to run with minor modifications

```html
function getContent(txtBeschreibung) {
   let val = $(txtBeschreibung).val();
   console.log(val);
}
```

It looks like you need to wrap the reference (this) in a dollar-sign to perform  jQuery operations on it.